# ManyToOne Cascade causes repeated persists in the mother table

Tags: java, jpa, ejb

I have two entities: Questionnaire and QuestionnaireTime. Questionnaire's id is a foreign key in QuestionnaireTime. So the relationship in my QuestionnaireTime entity looks like this:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "questionnaireid", referencedColumnName = "id")
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Questionnaire questionnaireid;
```

So what I'm trying to do is to add multiple QuestionnaireTime records for one Questionnaire. If I remove the CascadeType.PERSIST part in my relationship, my persist is not done. And when I use cascade, I get several new records in my main table Questionnaire and that's not what I want.

For example when I want to add three QuestionnaireTime's for a certain Questionnaire, the three records are inserted in my QuestionnaireTime table but also 3+1 records are added in  Questionnaire.

If you need more explanation. This is my managed bean, the part that I'm trying to add multiple QuestionnaireTime records in one Questionnaire:
NB - current is my Questionnaire object

```
else if (current.getType().equals("frequent")) {
                int iteration = 1;
                currentQuestionnaireTime = new QuestionnaireTime();
                if (!selectDateList.isEmpty()) {
                    for (String insertedDate : selectDateList) {                    
                        currentQuestionnaireTime.setId(0);
                        currentQuestionnaireTime.setQuestionnaireid(current);
                        getEjbQuestionnaireTimeFacade().create(currentQuestionnaireTime);
                        iteration++;
                    }
                }
            }
            try {
                getFacade().create(current); // my Questionnaire facade
            } catch (EJBException ejbe) {
                ejbe.getCause();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things,

questionnaireid - this is a very bad field name, questionnaire would make sense.

currentQuestionnaireTime.setId(0); - you should not be changing the id of an existing object, instead create a new object

getEjbQuestionnaireTimeFacade().create() - what does this do?  If you need the reference to the current, then the current should be persisted first.  If you EJB remote?  If it is, then either make it local, or ensure you use merge() not persist(), as you new object has a reference to a detached object.  Or find the reference in the current persistence context.